# Accessing loop variable within anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

The error that I am getting is that within `public void pressed`, the variable `i` cannot be accessed unless the `int` is set as `final`. But, if I set it as `final`, the `i++` becomes the error. I am stuck unless I can access the `i` variable from within my inline function. Is this possible?

```
for (int i = 0; i < level.myItems.size(); i++) {
    itemsInInventory[i].setButtonListener(new UIButtonListener() {
        public void pressed(UIButton button, Sprites sprite) {
            itemsInInventory[i].performAction();;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's not an inline function, it's an anonymous class.

Comment: Make `i` a global variable within the class. Then you won't have to make it final and you can also access it within `public void pressed`

Answer (score 4):

You can declare a `final` local variable inside the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < level.myItems.size(); i++){
    final int j = i;
    itemsInInventory[i].setButtonListener(new UIButtonListener(){
        public void pressed(UIButton button, Sprites sprite){
            itemsInInventory[j].performAction();
        }
    });
}
```

Or, better, since you just need the button, not `i`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < level.myItems.size(); i++){
    final UIButton btn = itemsInInventory[i];
    btn.setButtonListener(new UIButtonListener(){
        public void pressed(UIButton button, Sprites sprite){
            btn.performAction();
        }
    });
}
```

Or even better (since presumably the first argument to `pressed` is the button itself):

```
for(int i = 0; i < level.myItems.size(); i++){
    itemsInInventory[i].setButtonListener(new UIButtonListener(){
        public void pressed(UIButton button, Sprites sprite){
            button.performAction();
        }
    });
}
```

Note that with the last version, you don't need a separate `UIButtonListener` for each button. Just set them all to have the same listener and the listener will dispatch to the appropriate button automatically:

```
UIButtonListener listener = new UIButtonListener(){
    public void pressed(UIButton button, Sprites sprite){
        button.performAction();
    }
};
for(int i = 0; i < level.myItems.size(); i++){
    itemsInInventory[i].setButtonListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `final int j = i;`

Comment: Oh gosh that was quick! Thanks a ton! I dont know why I could figure that one out!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - That's exactly what I meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your variable's lifetime is tied to the for loop, but the object you're creating can live on forever. In order to do something like this, the variable needs to be final so the compiler knows that it can make a hidden copy of it inside the anonymous class. You can do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < foo; i++) {
    final int index = i;
    ... anonymous class using "index"...
}
```

Java 8 makes this a bit simpler but is only available on Android N and newer.

Comment: `final int index = i;`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks, too much Groovy.